# Unit testing Controllers with 'withFormat' and html content type gives empty response unless 'render' explicitly called

Tags: unit-testing, grails

In a Grails 2.1.1 application, I'm trying to unit test a controller that uses
'withFormat' to render the response either as HTML or JSON. However responding to the HTML content type always results in
an empty response in my test, unless I wrap it in a closure and explicitly call 'render'. For JSON,
it sends back the expected response.

Controller:

```
import grails.converters.JSON

class TestController {
def formatWithHtmlOrJson() {
    withFormat {
        html someContent:"should be HTML" 
        json {render new Expando(someContent:"should be JSON")  as JSON}
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@TestFor(TestController)
class TestControllerTests {
    void testForJson() {
        response.format = "json"
        controller.formatWithHtmlOrJson()
        println("resp: $response.contentAsString")
        assert response.json.properties.someContent == "should be JSON"
    }

    void testForHtml() {
        response.format = "html"
        controller.formatWithHtmlOrJson()
        println("resp: $response.contentAsString")
        // fails here, response is empty
        assert response.text
        //never gets this far
        assert response.contentAsString.contains("HTML")
    }
}
```

As described above, for JSON this works, but for HTML I always get an empty
response, unless I wrap the html check in a closure and explicitly call render, as below:

```
withFormat {
    html {
        render someContent:"should be HTML" 
    }
```

The docs suggest I shouldn't need to do this, e.g. :

```
withFormat {
    html bookList: books
    js { render "alert('hello')" }
    xml { render books as XML }
}
```

from http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Controllers/withFormat.html

Frustratingly, the grails docs on testing mention the use of withFormat but only give examples for testing xml/json, and nothing for the html response.

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#unitTestingControllers

Can anyone explain this discrepancy, or how I might work around it in my
tests?

Comment: Can you post the code of your unit test?

Comment: Added test code and fleshed out controller code.

Comment: assert response.json in a html test?

Comment: Sorry, cut and paste error, fixed now.

Comment: I created your example here, and get the same error. And the code in the docs show an example only with render (maybe because of that?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured this out.

In the documentation (http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#unitTestingControllers), it mentions this way of testing a controller response under *Testing Actions Which Return A Map*
:

```
import grails.test.mixin.*
@TestFor(SimpleController)
class SimpleControllerTests {

    void testShowBookDetails() {
        def model = controller.showBookDetails()
        assert model.author == 'Alvin Plantinga' 
    }
}
```

The same approach works for controller methods that use *withFormat*.

So for my original example above:

```
withFormat {
    html someContent:"should be HTML" 
...
```

the test becomes:

```
void testForHtml() {
    response.format = "html"
    def model = controller.formatWithHtmlOrJson()
    assert model.someContent == "should be HTML"
}
```

The documentation is a tad confusing as the *withFormat* section makes no mention of this approach.

Worth noting, should anyone else encounter this, that if the html block is inside a closure, the map isn't returned, but rather the value of the map entry, so for the controller code:

```
withFormat{
    html{
        someContent:"should be HTML" 
    }...
```

the test check becomes:

```
     assert model == "should be HTML"
```

Alternatively, if you can modify the controller code, returning the result inside a map lets you use the dot notation to check the element value. For this code:

```
 withFormat {
    html {
        [someContent:"should be HTML"] 
    }....
```

the test check is:

```
assert model.someContent == "should be HTML"
```

Also worth noting, in my original example that **doesn't** use a closure for the HTML type, you **can't** return the value as a map- it results in a compile error.

```
//Don't do this, won't compile
    withFormat {
        html [someContent:"should be HTML"]         
    ...
```

Comment: I had the same issue with text format. `response.format = "text"` did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
withFormat {
    html {
        println("html")
        [new Expando(test:"html")]
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't make a difference unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion provided in the document does not use a `closure` and has this verbiage "*Grails searches for a view called grails-app/views/book/list.html.gsp and if that is not found fallback to grails-app/views/book/list.gsp*".

When you use a `closure` for `html` then we have to either return a `model` to the action or `render` the content. Since in this case you are using the `html` `closure` the content has to  be rendered.

Using a Closure (Your use case passed)

```
withFormat{
   html {
      test: "HTML Content" //This will not render any content
      render(test: "HTML Content") //This has to be used
   }
}
```

Comment: I mentioned in my post that the only way to get this test to pass is to explicitly call render. I've tried both with and without a closure for the html content type.