# How do I configure mime types in a grails Spock test?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, controller, spock, grails-2.3

Grails 2.3.10.

How can I configure the available mime types for content type negotiation in a Grails Spock test?

When I try to tell the controller to produce JSON content, it seems to want to return an HTTP 406 error. I send in the Accept header in my test code; but, the parser is not able to match it because HTML is the only MIME type that's configured.

**My use case...**

I have implemented a controller action using the Grails *respond* method which can return a JSON response. When I hit the endpoint using a REST API call, I am able to get back JSON output (even if no Accept header is specified).

The controller code:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
class MyObjectController {
    static allowedMethods = [save: 'POST']
    static responseFormats = ['json']
    def myService

    @Transactional
    def save(MyObject obj) {
        obj.validate()
        if (obj.hasErrors()) {
            respond obj.getErrors(), [status: BAD_REQUEST]
        }

        myService.addNewCustomer(obj)

        respond obj, [formats: responseFormats]
    }
}
```

And my test code:

```
@TestFor(MyObjectController)
class MyObjectControllerSpec extends Specification {
    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "test save - json success"() {
        given:
        def myObj = new MyObject()
        controller.myService= Mock(MyObjectService)

        when:
        request.addHeader "Accept", "application/json"
        controller.save(individual)

        then:
        response.status == HttpStatus.CREATED.value()
        response.text == "{}"   //.text is giving me an empty string
        response.json.x == x    //.json throws an exception (parsing an empty string)
    }
}
```

I have verified in the debugger that *obj* has a valid value and that the *respond* method is invoked on the last line of the controller action.

What I am finding is that inside the Grails **ResponseMimeTypesApi** class, the **DefaultAcceptHeaderParser** is getting constructed with only the HTML mime type. Even though the JSON accept header is being read correctly, the **DefaultAcceptHeaderParser** isn't able to understand it because no mime types are configured.

How do I control the mime types that get sent to **ResponseMimeTypesApi** in my unit test spec?

**Edit**

I have also tried setting the *response.format* property, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16195621/166850); but, to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I could write the test that I wanted by converting from a unit to an integration test.

1. Move the test to the **/integration** path.
2. Change the test spec to extend **IntegrationSpec**
3. **@Autowire** the class under test instead of using **@TestFor**:
4. Set **controller.response.format = 'json'** and call **controller.request.addHeader 'Accept', 'application/json'**

Answer (score 0):

If you assign a value to `request.json` that will set the content type.  You can also set the content type explicitly with something like `request.contentType = 'application/json'` or `request.contentType = JSON_CONTENT_TYPE`.  For a list of the content type constants available in your unit tests see the "Testing Mime Type Handling" section under http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#unitTestingControllers.

Another resource to look at is the unit tests at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/4f8d1a605cde60a4a00021102959578dae8bc5a8/grails-test-suite-web/src/test/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/binding/json/JsonBindingSpec.groovy and https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/801d507cf3fec5866baa14f6d6b0acd05aa5fb56/grails-test-suite-web/src/test/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/binding/xml/XmlBindingSpec.groovy.

I hope that helps.

**EDIT:**

To clarify...

I mentioned assigning a value to `request.json`.  The value you assign to that of course is JSON, not the content type.  Like this...

```
request.json = '''
{
    "name": "Douglas", "age": "42"
}
'''
```

When you do that, the content type gets set automatically.

Comment: Jeff, thanks for your reply; however, this question is about the MIME type of the response, not about binding request data. The two example links you provided don't show how this is done and I couldn't figure it out from the Grails docs.

Comment: Apologies.  That is my mistake.